# Why would gamma be different from 1 in gradient boosting

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

As a learning exercise to understand the algorithm, I am implementing gradient boosting for regression, based on the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting#Algorithm). I think I get the gist of it, but I have been stumped by a question, which leads me to wonder if I am misunderstanding it.

Here is my understanding:
* at iteration n, I have a predictor F_n available,
* compute the residuals r_n = Y - F_n(X)
* fit a model f_n to the residuals, minimizing some cost function L
* find gamma_n to minimize L(Y, F_n(X) + gamma_n * f_n(X))
* iterate with F_n+1 = F_n + gamma_n * f_n

I have tried this out with L = SSR / sum of squares of prediction errors, fitting stumps as well as regression trees to minimize the same cost function. What puzzled me is that gamma always ended up being 1.0.

Which leads to my question: **why would gamma not be 1.0?**

I can think of 3 reasons:
1. I am misunderstanding something in the algorithm,
2. I happen to use the same cost function to fit my weak learners and the combination, which might not always be the case (I might want to, say, minimize manhattan distance overall, but fit weak learners using a different cost function),
3. Gamma could be searched on a test set different from the training set, to avoid over-fitting (which is not explicit in the Wikipedia description).

The short version: am I missing something? Should I expect gamma = 1.0 if I use SSR as a cost? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, the nagging doubt that I am missing something is driving me nuts.

Comment: In your search for gamma, are you limiting the search to [0,1]? If so, it might be that the weak learners are fitting the data well enough to be entirely trusted.

Comment: At that point, I think the following is true: if both weak learners and overall procedure use SSR as a cost function, then gamma will be 1.0 always.